# How can I do/enable "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" option in firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, caching, firefox-addon, browser-cache

- I have found "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" opting in new version of chrome browser.
- How can I do same in Firefox ?
- Problem is I am getting logged out from website after clear all cache in Firefox.I want to find such solution for Firefox as chrome given.

Comment: Please provide comments if you downvote this question.

Comment: Since Google points to this question when I search "empty cache and hard reload", and this question is closed, I'll post my workaround here:
1. Open the inspector (CTRL+SHIFT+I),
2. Go to the network tab,
3. Check "disable cache",
4. Reload with CTRL+SHIFT+R

Answer (score 1):

**Windows/Linux:**

- Hold the Ctrl key and press the F5 key.
- Or, hold down Ctrl and ⇧ Shift and then press R.

**Mac:**

- Hold down the ⇧ Shift and click the Reload button.
- Or, hold down ⌘ Cmd and ⇧ Shift and then press R.

Comment: I think this is same option available in Chrome. But it is not clear cache all time. Please share more info for this.